# Javascript appending an object to an object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to Javascript and Im having a hard time trying to figure the following out. I need to append a javascript object to the end of another javascript object. I know the preferred way to do this is to store it in an array and use `.push` but that does not work for my use case as I need the format of the JSON to stay the way it is and not add the `[]` when doing the push method.

Below is my javascript:

```
var hours_json = 
{
  "type": "COLUMN",
  "properties": {
    "span": 2
   },
   "children": [
     {
       "rest of the code here"
     },
   ],
 };
 var hours_part_2 = {
   "type": "COLUMN",
      "properties": {
         "span": 10,
       },
       "children": [],
 };
```

I want to append `hours_part_2` to the end of `hour_json` and for the output to look like:

```
{
  "type": "COLUMN",
  "properties": {
    "span": 2
   },
   "children": [
     {
       "rest of the code here"
     },
   ],
 },
 {
   "type": "COLUMN",
      "properties": {
         "span": 10,
       },
       "children": [],
 },
 "rest of code"
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: `hours_json = [hours_json, hours_part_2]`?, you can't have a pair of objects just "attached" end to end with each other, you have to store them in an array or give them keys and put them in another object

Comment: Yeah, they should by in an array like `[ {obj}, {obj2} ]` or in a larger object like: `{ title: "hours", "object1": {obj1}, "object2": {obj2} }`

Comment: Please be aware that there is no JSON in the question. Both `hours_json` and `hours_part_2` are JS objects, not JSON

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to store in an array with the push method as you have said.

To 'remove' the [ and ] you can use the spread (...) operator, read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```js
var hours_array = [];
var hours_json = {
  "type": "COLUMN",
  "properties": {
    "span": 2
   },
   "children": [
      {
        "rest_of_the_code_here": ""
      }
    ]
 };
 
var hours_part_2 = {
  "type": "COLUMN",
  "properties": {
    "span": 10,
  },
  "children": []
};
 
hours_array.push(hours_json);
hours_array.push(hours_part_2);

console.log(...hours_array);
```

Comment: Ok so how would I return that? Like at the end of the javascript I have return "some variable", how would I format the hours_array to remove the [ ]? I looked at the spread stuff but all it has is console.logs

Answer (score 0):

you need an outer object to bind them both

```
hours: {};
hours.part1 = hours_jsonl;
hours.part2 = hours_part_2;
```

this would give the final results of

```
{
    part1: {
  "type": "COLUMN",
  "properties": {
    "span": 2
   },
   "children": [
      {
        "rest_of_the_code_here": ""
      }
    ]
 },
    part2: {
  "type": "COLUMN",
  "properties": {
    "span": 10,
  },
  "children": []
} 
}
```

But yeah. An array is by far the best approach. Then just `array.forEach(el => //do something);` to handle the objects.